# Split delimited cells and highlight if cell contains a certain value

Tags: vba, split, delimiter

I have an excel file where each row of a certain column has data (both dates and integers) delimited by "|". With VBA, I want to highlight a cell if it contains a value greater than 3,000,000.

Below is my code. sh2lrow is the last row of my current sheet (sheet 2). ioSched is the column I'm working with. Can you help me with a better solution? I'm splitting the cells, then if it's an integer, converting the string to an integer, and then highlighting in red if greater than 3,000,000.

```
    For i = 2 To sh2lRow
        splitBudget = Split((sh2.Cells(i, ioSched)), "|")
            For Each Item In splitBudget
                If IsNumeric(Item) Then
                    finalNumber = CInt(Item)
                Else: finalNumber = 0
            End If
        If finalNumber > 3000000 Then sh2.Cells(i, ioSched).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        Next
    Next i
```

[image]

Comment: Which comes first: `date | number` or `number | date`? And are number with thousand separators?

Comment: Do you happen to have `On Error Resume Next` in the procedure?  `CInt(Item)` will overflow if the value is higher than 32,767.  You need finalNumber to be a `Long` - use `CLng(Item)` instead.

Comment: It is date | date | number, sometimes repeated (i.e. date | date | number | date | date | number). No thousand separators. I put an example in the "image of excel file here." I'm getting stuck also because I want to highlight if any of the numbers in a cell are greater than 3000000.

Comment: The first line in your sample data will not only overflow an `Integer`, it will also overflow a `Long`. What are the highest values you expect to see there?

Comment: Shouldn't exceed 10,000,000

Comment: Thank you for your help everyone! The code above works but as CLng(Item) like Comintern suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using string functions, `Mid()` and `Instr()`, to parse out the number for the formatting. Below assumes the column's pattern is `date|number`:

```
For i = 2 To sh2lRow
    finalnumber = CLng(Mid(Worksheets(1).Cells(i, ioSched), _
                           InStr(Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 1), "|") + 1))

    If finalnumber > 3000000 Then Worksheets(1).Cells(i, ioSched).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
```

Should the column's pattern be either `date|number` and `number|date` (without space before or after pipe), add `Left()` string function with a conditional check:

```
For i = 2 To sh2lRow
    cellValue = Worksheets(1).Cells(i, ioSched)
    If IsNumeric(Left(cellValue, InStr(cellValue, "|") - 1)) Then
        finalnumber = CLng(Left(cellValue, InStr(cellValue, "|") - 1))
    Else
        finalnumber = CLng(Mid(cellValue, InStr(cellValue, "|") + 1))
    End If

    If finalnumber > 3000000 Then Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
Next i
```